# table size not reducing after purged table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, diskspace

I recently perform a purging on my application table. total record of 1.1 millions with the disk space used 11.12GB.

I had deleted 860k records and remain 290k records, but why my space used only drop to 11.09GB?

I monitor the detail on **report - disk usage - disk space used by data files - space used**.

Is it that i need to perfrom shrink data file? This has been puzzle me long time.

Comment: What's the platform? Which OS? Which database engine? MySQL? SQL Server? Something else? And yes, most database engines won't release free space to the OS until you run a compaction step.

Comment: Windows 2003. SQL server 2005 running on cluster environment. I have 2 db instance. db A give me significant space used reduce after i purge the record. but for DB B after I perform purging. not giving me any improvement of disk space used reduce. what you mean by compaction step?

Answer (score 3):

For MS SQL Server, rebuild the clustered indexes.

You have only deleted rows: not reclaimed space.

[DBCC DBREINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181671.aspx) or [ALTER INDEX ... WITH REBUILD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388.aspx) depending on verison

(It's MS SQL because the disk space report is in SSMS)

Comment: ALTER INDEX ... WITH REBUILD highly preferred in SQL Server 2005 and up.

Comment: Wow, rebuilding the index reduced my table's space from 600MB to 200KB after a big purge. This is the command I used: `ALTER TABLE <table name> REBUILD;`

Comment: @JohnnyOshika yes, this implicitly rebuilds the clustered index (if there is one) or the table itself (if no clustered index). Any non-clustered indexes are not rebuilt by ALTER TABLE

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly call some operation (specific to your database management system) that will shrink the data file. The database engine doesn't shrink the file when you delete records, that's for optimization purposes - shrinking is time-consuming.

Comment: can I shrink data file while db is running? the db is about 11GB. Is it it willtake long time to shrink?

Comment: No idea. You should consult the manual of the database software you use.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is like with mail folders in Thunderbird: If you delete something, it's just marked as deleted, but to get higher performance, the space isn't freed. So most of your 11.09 GB will now contain either your old data or 0's. Shrink data file will "compress" (or "clean") this by creating a new file that'll only contain the actual data that is left.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to shrink the table. I know that SQL server doesn't do it by default for you, I would guess this is for reasons of performance, maybe other DBs are the same.